# SQL server translation to Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datetime

I'm translating an sql server database to postgres, and got stucked in this function

```
CREATE   function [dbo].[GetEndOfTheDayMoment](@date datetime)
returns datetime
as
begin
  return CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(11),@date, 111 ) + ' 23:59:59.997', 111)
end
```

I dont know how to write the return statement in postgres language. I stated with postgres in the last weeks, so can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-function/) would be a good first stop if you're stuck. Don't forget to show us your PostgreSQL attempt as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this simply returns the input date/time to the same day, right before midnight.

The translation to Postgres depends a bit on the data type of your input.

If your input is a `date` value (rather than a `timestamp` value), you can use this:

```sql
create or replace function dbo.getendofthedaymoment(p_date date)
  returns timestamp -- or maybe timestamp with time zone??
as
$$
  select p_date + time '23:59:59.997';
$$
language sql
stable;
```

If your input value is a `timestamp`, you can use the following:

```sql
create or replace function dbo.getendofthedaymoment(p_date timestamp)
  returns timestamp -- or maybe timestamp with time zone??
as
$$
  select p_date::date + time '23:59:59.997';
$$
language sql
stable;
```

As Postgres supports function overloading, you can define both functions and Postgres will choose the appropriate one depending on your input value.

You might also want to add a version that accepts a `timestamp with time zone` (aka `timestamptz`)

---

The `dbo` schema is not a default schema in Postgres. So you either need to create it manually, or create the function in a different schema instead (e.g. `public`)